# Draw 3 images and text in listview

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm not using mfc.

I make my own list-view (to shown data in table)

```
hListView = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT |
    LVS_EDITLABELS, 0, 0, h_rcl.right - h_rcl.left, h_rcl.bottom - h_rcl.top,
    hwnd_main, (HMENU)1000, hInstance, NULL);
```

But in one of column i want to show data like:

"Text  | Text " (ofc as  i want to put a img)

So my table would look like:

```
# | column1 | column 2
1 | "text <img> | text <img>" | text
```

Best Regards

Hahaha:D Right...

How to draw this images with this text?
I dont think that it is possible with:

```
ListView_SetItemText(hListView, items_num, 1, "test");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either:

1. enable the `LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES` window style and then specify a per-item per-column image index into an ImageList that you associate with the ListView.
2. [custom-draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff919569.aspx#list_tree) the ListView items.